How do i add a "for" loop in VHDL
I'm trying to make this "for" loop work but im stuck with the same error: "Illegal concurrent statement".
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;


entity circ is
    generic ( Width : integer:=8;
          WidthZ : integer:=4);

    port ( z : out std_logic_vector ( WidthZ-1 downto 0 );
           x1 : in std_logic_vector ( Width-1 downto 0 );
           x2 : in std_logic_vector ( Width-1 downto 0 ));
end entity circ;

architecture funcLog_circ of circ is
    signal count : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    begin 
        for i in 0 to 7 loop
            if (x1(i) xor x2(i)) then 
                count <= count + 1;
            end if;
        end loop;
    z <= count;
end architecture;

I really have no clue on why i cannot use the "for" loop.

It depends on what you want to model with the loop: different things happening in sequence, or different things happening in parallel.

A loop statement is a sequential statement. "Sequential statements are used to define algorithms for the execution of a subprogram or process; they execute in the order in which they appear."

You need to:

Put it in a process
Make count a variable as when you iterate across an object in a process without time passing, you need an object that updates immediately
If you want count to update every time the process runs, then you need to assign count to 0 at the beginning of the process.
Use a type that allows you to add 1, such as unsigned or integer.

    CountItProc : process (X1, X2)
      variable count : unsigned(3 downto 0) ;
    begin 
        count := (others => '0') ;
        for i in 0 to 7 loop
            if (x1(i) xor x2(i)) then 
                count := count + 1;
            end if;
        end loop;
        z <= std_logic_vector(count);
    end process ; 


A for loop is not a concurrent statement. So it can only be used inside a process:
process(x1, x2)
begin
    for i in 0 to 7 loop
        if (x1(i) xor x2(i)) then 
            count <= count + 1;
        end if;
    end loop;
end process;

Don't forget to intialize the signal count, otherwise your design will not work. For example by
signal count : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := (others => '0');

Be aware, that count will be incremented only by 1, independent from how often your if-condition in the loop will be TRUE.

Signal updates don't take effect until a process suspends, with a sensitivity list in an implicit wait statement as the last statement. There's also only one entry for a particular simulation time in a projected output waveform queue so only the last assignment to count has any effect, always ending up with either "0001" or "0000". There's also no use clause making an overload for "+" directly visible with operands and result of type std_logic_vector.
